# Can't set a span's content within an anchor

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

I have this field.

```
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="20.00">
```

I have this link.

```
<a target='_blank' href="https://PayPal.me/MyAccount/<span id='myspan'>0.00</span>">click here</a>
```

When I try to insert the amount value ($20.00) into myspan, I get this error:
**"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"**

I'm using this Javascript that is at the bottom of the file.

```
    <script type ="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      myFunction();
    })

    function myFunction() {
     var thisamount = document.getElementById("cart_total").value;
     alert(thisamount);
     document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML = thisamount;
    }
    </script>
```

What the frig am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do by putting a span in a link?

Comment: You can't put elements in the attributes of other elements.

Comment: So I can't add a value to the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your anchor should look like this
`<a target='_blank' id="myHref" href="#"><span id='myspan'>0.00</span>USD</a>`

then

```
function myFunction() {
     var thisamount = document.getElementById("cart_total").value;
     alert(thisamount);
     document.getElementById("myHref").href = `https://PayPal.me/MyAccount/${thisamount}`;
     document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML = thisamount;
    }
```

Comment: I think he may be trying to change the URL to include the amount.

Comment: Exactly. Just trying to make it easier for the user.

Comment: @RickyD ok i updated my answer. i believe this is what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

1. You referenced cart_total but your field is named amount
2. A span inside of quotes is part of a textnode, it is no longer a separate DOM node

```js
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        myFunction();
    });

    function myFunction() {
        var thisamount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
        console.log("thisamount", thisamount);
        let url = `https://PayPal.me/MyAccount/${thisamount}usd`;
        console.log("url", url);
        document.getElementById("paypalLink").setAttribute("href", url);
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="$20.00">
<a id="paypalLink" target='_blank' href="https://PayPal.me/MyAccount/">Pay Me!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. the first thing you should declare the function before the call

   ```
      <script type ="text/javascript">
       function myFunction() {
        var thisamount = document.getElementById("cart_total").value;
        alert(thisamount);
        document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML = thisamount;
       }

      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
       myFunction();
      })
     </script>
   ```
2. u can't add an element inside another element attribute

   ```
   <a target='_blank' href="https://PayPal.me/MyAccount">
   <span id='myspan'>0.00</span>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be something like this (i put notes inside the snippet):

```js
document.querySelector('#amount').addEventListener('change', function() { // add change event to the input in order to update the current href
    document.querySelector('#sendMoney').setAttribute('href', 'https://PayPal.me/MyAccount/'+this.value+'USD'); // set the href 
    document.querySelector('#sendMoney').textContent = this.value+'$'; // set text content with current value
});
```

```html
<label for="amount">Set amount</label>
<input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" value="20.00" />
<br />
<a id="sendMoney" href="https://PayPal.me/MyAccount/" target="_blank"></a>
```